# Wait input end before executing next code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nwjs

I'm using this piece of code to to try triggering an input and then read the file path, so I can load it as text in a `div`:

```
var fileinput = $("input[id=fileDialog]").trigger('click');

var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function(err, txt) {
  if (err) {
    return;
  }

  document.getElementById('content').innerText=txt
});
```

Problem is, it seems that the jQuery part is async, so the following code doesn't wait for it to finish, and that generate problems.

How can I make the code wait for the input to close before executing?

Comment: could you listen for the change event?

Comment: you can use **fs.readFileSync**

Comment: it is quite hard to help yo without know what you are trying to do. What part of the code yould be launched when?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your **fs.readFile** Asynchronously reads the entire contents of a file while execution moves to next statement.

you can use **Synchronous version of `fs.readFile()`. i.e. `fs.readFileSync` that returns the contents of the path.**

Full details are here https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options